# Where does Steam download apps to on Mac? (What's the save path?)

Tags: macos, steam, file-location

Where does Steam download apps to on Mac? (What's the save path?)

Where is the local content stored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Update about this location from Valve, today](http://store.steampowered.com/news/3857/). They received obviously many complaints about the Documents folder, so they are changing that soon.

> (...) As soon as the feature to help users
>   uninstall Steam completely when they
>   drag it to the Trash is complete, we
>   will be moving the game content folder
>   into **"~/Library/Application
>   Support/Steam"**.

Comment: @macek - think about updating the accepted answer later, when this change will be effective, since it won't be in "documents" anymore, then.

Answer (score 7):

The default is your Documents directory.

Comment: Is this configurable?

Comment: Yes, games are stored in `~/Documents/Steam Content`.

Comment: @macek yes, see http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=915169#11 for instructions

Comment: You were lucky - I signed up and downloaded Portal earlier this week and it dumped 5 GB of stuff in my root directory.

Answer (score 1):

[Move or hide Steam content from Documents](http://dae.cyberic.eu/blog/hide-steam-content-folder-from-documents-in-mac-os-x/)